# JAXB Unmarshalling not unmarshalling nested list

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've been coming across a new issue in my JAXB unmarshalling

Given this string as an input

```
<ruleGroup id="1602" name="TestObject">
    <simple column="simple" type="value" operator="equals" value="1" not="true"/>
</ruleGroup>
```

The class does not parse the nested list element, only normal attributes (represented as a JSON):

```
{"id":1602,"name":"TestObject"}
```

What is the issue here? My classes are:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ruleGroup")
public class RuleGroup {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public Long id;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "simple")
    public List<SimpleXML> simple;
}
```

and

```
public class SimpleXML {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "column")
    public String column = null;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    public String type = null;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "operator")
    public String operator = null;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "value")
    public String value = null;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "not")
}
```

My unmarshalling is pretty standard:

```
RuleGroup rule;
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RuleGroup.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(test);
JAXBElement<RuleGroup> root = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(reader), RuleGroup.class);
rule = (RuleGroup) root.getValue();
```

So I don't know what the issue could be. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Running the code in Java 8 resolved the issue. If anyone wants to clarify why the Marshaller is affected by that I'd love to know the answer